# Is it necessary to have the Publishing features enabled, to be able to Add and Use Content Search WebPart

Tags: 2013, administration, publishing-site, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

I am working on sharepoint server 2013. and i have added a Team site collection under the root `http://servername/` and i did not enable the publishing site collection feature.

now i wanted to use the Content Search WebPart. so i read this article:-

https://nikpatel.net/2014/02/28/content-query-web-part-vs-content-by-search-web-part/

which mention that to have the content search web part available i have to enable the publishing features. but in my case i have a Team site collection and i did not enable the publishing features, but when i edit the home page >> Add WebPart >> content Rollout >> i can add and use the content Search web part, without having to enable the publishing features. so not sure if it is mandatory to enable the publishing features inside my site collection to be able to use the content Search WebPart as mentioned on the above link ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not mandatory, you are right you can add the `Content Search WebPart` (`CSWP`) without activating `publishing feature`.

[image]

The `Content Search WebPart` requires that you have configured Search Application Service.

[image]

The `publishing feature` is required in case you need to use the `Content Query Web Part` (`CQWP`).

Comment: so you mean what is mentioned inside this link https://nikpatel.net/2014/02/28/content-query-web-part-vs-content-by-search-web-part/ is not 100% accurate ?? as it is saying that Content search web part is only available when u enable the publishing features...

Comment: I can add it without activating publishing feature and you also can do that? So What do you think @johnG :) ? Meanwhile, you can check the official link for CSWP that not mentioned that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163789.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. I think the article author need to say it's used with the cross-publishing site. again The Content Search WebPart requires SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Edition with configured Search Application Service.